# I am trying to stream an audio file in my android media player app which is placed in aws s3 bucket

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to achieve this through URL and when I add the s3 URL of that item activity in my app is getting crashed...
how can I stream the audio file from s3 in android studio?

In the below code with the commented line it is working fine but with s3 item URL app is crashing

```
private void prepareMediaPlayer(){
    try{
       // mediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");
      mediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://testing-ariya.s3.ap-   south1.amazonaws.com/Faded_320(PaglaSongs).mp3");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            textTotalDuration.setText(milisecToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));

    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible since AWS bucket is not a "streaming" service.

Comment: The URL should be `s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws` not `s3.ap-   south1.amazonaws`, though it appears you haven't made the object public, so the player will be unable to load it.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez did it using presigned URL

Comment: @AnonCoward thnx I did try after making it public, didn't work but any how I changed the link and did it using presigned URL

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez really need ur help to achieve this. What should I use instead?

Comment: You can use mux.com or Cloudflare stream

Comment: We're going to need more detail on what "crash" and "didn't work" mean.  Playing an MP3 from a HTTPS server like S3 that supports byte-ranges should absolutely work.

Comment: Anon Coward and sent a request in linkedin with a note please check...... plz check this query https://stackoverflow.com/q/75123059/20839793 Need urgent assistance from you sir